# Deleting keys anywhere in nested JSON

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to delete all occurrences of a key in a nested JSON string with Ruby, but the structure of the JSON is unpredictable. For example,

```
{
  "id": null,
  "created-at": null,
  "updated-at": null,
  "locale": null,
  "name": null,
  "description": null,
  "item": {
    "id": null,
    "created-at": null,
    "updated-at": null,
    "description": null,
    "item-number": null,
    "name": null
  },
  "uom": {
    "id": null,
    "created-at": null,
    "updated-at": null,
    "code": null,
    "name": null
  }
}
```

and I want to remove all occurrences of "updated-at", wherever they are located.

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone give a pointer what I'm doing wrong?

```
def strip_keys(json, targetkey)
  json.each_with_object([]) do |record, results|
    record.each do |key, value|
      if value.is_a? Hash
        results << { key => strip_keys(value, targetkey) }
      else
        results << { key => value } unless key == targetkey
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying your existing JSON object:

```
require 'json'

file = File.read('./example.json')
json = JSON.parse(file)

def recursively_remove_property!(target, property)
  target.delete_if do |k, v|
    if k == property
      true
    elsif v.is_a?(Hash)
      recursively_remove_property!(v, property)
      false
    end
  end
end

recursively_remove_property!(json, "updated-at")
```

Comment: If you're using rails (like one of the question tags suggests), there might be a way to use [Hash#except](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) but I haven't used it before myself

Comment: This works wonderfully, thanks! You did have the arguments flipped though when calling the function (should be recursively_remove_property!(json, "updated-at")

Comment: oh right, fixed. I modified the method where I was testing it, but forgot to fix-up the call when I pasted it here. Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_keys_deep!(h)
  h.keys.each do |k|
    h.delete k if [:updated-at].include? k # you can add other keys in the array to being removed
    if h[k].kind_of?(Array)
      h[k].each do |h2|
        remove_keys_deep!(h2)
      end
    elsif h[k].kind_of?(Hash)
      remove_keys_deep!(h[k])
    end
  end
end
```

And then,

```
h = {...} # your hash
remove_keys_deep!(h)
h #=> your hash with selected keys removed
```

Be carefull with the keys, they all should be :key-name or :"key-name", not both.
Bonus, that method works too if a key has an array with hashes like

```
{
  id: 123,
  users: [
    {id: 234,
     created-at: '12/12/12'
    },
    {id: 345,
     updated-at: '11/11/11'
    }
  ]
}
```